# How to solve this definite integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos^9(x)}{\sin^3(x)+\cos^3(x)}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble evaluating the following integral:
$$
\int^\pi_0 \frac{\cos^9(x)}{\sin^3(x)+\cos^3(x)}dx
$$

I tried to convert it into an algebraic function by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sec^{11}(x)$ and substituting $\tan(x)=t$ as

$$
\int^\pi_0 \frac{\cos^9(x)\cdot \sec^{11}(x)}{(\sin^3(x)+\cos^3(x))\cdot \sec^{11}(x)}dx
$$

$$
\int^\pi_0 \frac{\sec^2(x)}{(\tan^3(x)+1)\cdot (\tan^2(x)+1)^4}dx
$$

Substituting $\tan(x)=t$,

$$
\int^0_0 \frac{dt}{(t^3+1)\cdot (t^2+1)^4}
$$

But now both upper and lower limit become $0$ so apparently this is not the right approach, so how do I go about solving it?

Comment: Before you do anything, you need to decide what you want to do with the singularity at $x = \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @achillehui I haven't dealt with such integrals before, what are my options?

Comment: One option is compute the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) instead. Another option is lift the integral to a contour integral in complex plane and deform the contour around the pole at $x = \frac{3\pi}{4}$. If this is the first time you deal with this sort of integral, you should follow the Cauchy principle value route. You essentially need to split the integral to 2 regions $[0,\frac{3\pi}{4}-\epsilon], [\frac{3\pi}{4}+\epsilon,\pi]$ and take the limit $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$ at the end.

Comment: Sure the integral is not on $[0,\pi/2]$?

Comment: @achillehui Thank you very much.

Comment: @Did I don't anywhere to check, so can't say for sure but even if it is incorrect there is no harm in learning something new :)

Comment: "no harm in learning something new" Sure, and this is related how?

Comment: When you do your substitutions, the functions in your substitutions must be continuous over the required interval.  In this case, break it up into $(0, \frac {\pi}{2}), (\frac {\pi}{2}, \pi)$ and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the usage of the Cauchy principle value, let's define
$$ I_1 := \int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{\cos^9(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} {\rm d}x
\\ I_2 := \text{p. v.} \int_\frac\pi2^\pi \frac{\cos^9(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} {\rm d}x
$$

For $I_1$, by making a substitution and adding it to itself,
$$
I_1 = \int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{\sin^9(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} {\rm d}x
\\ = \frac12 \int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{\cos^9(x) +\sin^9(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} {\rm d}x
\\ = \frac12 \int_0^\frac\pi2 \left( \sin^6(x) + \cos^6(x) - \sin^3(x)\cos^3(x) \right) {\rm d}x
$$

For $I_2$, by making some substitutions,
$$
I_2 = \text{p. v.} \int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{\sin^9(x)}{\sin^3(x)-\cos^3(x)} {\rm d}x
\\  = \text{p. v.} \int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{-\cos^9(x)}{\sin^3(x)-\cos^3(x)} {\rm d}x
\\  = \frac12 \text{p. v.} \int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{\sin^9(x)-\cos^9(x)}{\sin^3(x)-\cos^3(x)} 
\\  = \frac12 \int_0^\frac\pi2 \left( \sin^6(x) + \cos^6(x) + \sin^3(x)\cos^3(x) \right) {\rm d}x
$$

Therefore,

$$
I_1 + I_2 = \text{p. v.} \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos^9(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} {\rm d}x
\\ = \int_0^\frac\pi2 \sin^6(x) + \cos^6(x) {\rm d}x
\\ = \int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac58 + \frac38 \cos(4x) {\rm d}x
\\ = \frac{5\pi}{16}
$$